# Is there any performance gain when using show/hide on imports in Dart?

Tags: performance, dart

In the documentation (https://dart.dev/language/libraries#importing-only-part-of-a-library) these keywords mention importing part of the library. Could we then understand that this would reduce final builds and also minimize the scans that IDEs do?

In the specification (https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/f65daa6ce01c7489be36e51c11ac95a2c0bb243d/working/1426-extension-types/feature-specification.md?plain=1#L591) these keywords only mention the control access.

Is there any performance gain in using show/hide or is your goal just to control access?

Answer (score 2):

No, there should not be any performance gains. `hide`/`show` *statically* (at compile-time) control access to symbols.  If there were any optimizations that could be made, it would be fairly trivial for the compiler to make them for you automatically.